# Xcode preprocessor, variables and "Will never be executed"

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

In a Swift based project, I need to set the value of a variable according to a preprocessor rule, like in the example below.

```
var doSomething = false
#if targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)
doSomething = true
#endif

if doSomething {
    print("Execute!")
}
```

If I build the code for an iOS simulator, Xcode will generate a "Will never be executed" warning at the `print("Execute!")` line. This make sense because preprocessor rules are evaluated before compilation and therefore the code above, when the target is an iOS simulator, corresponds to:

```
var doSomething = false

if doSomething {
    print("Execute!")
}
```

I just want to know if there is any advices for handling cases like that. Ideally, I would like to avoid using the preprocessor condition for every statement, like so:

```
#if targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)
print("Execute!")
#endif
```

but rely on a variable like the original example. I would also prefer to avoid completely disabling in Xcode the display of "Will never be executed" warnings for all source codes.

Is there a way to set the "doSomething" variable so that Xcode doesn't display the warning in a case like that?

Thank you

---

Update:

Thanks to Swinny89  for suggesting using a lazy var. It works great! Below you can find the final code:

```
lazy var doSomething: Bool = {
   #if targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)
      return true
   #else
      return false
   #endif
}()

if doSomething {
    print("Execute!")
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For readability and ease of use I would use a lazy var set by a function. This means that we're not wasteful in redefining the same thing twice and that this function will only be run once in setting your value:

```
///Var is true if running on macCatalyst, otherwise false
lazy var doSomething = {
    #if targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)
        return true
    #else
        return false
    #endif
}()

if doSomething {
    print("Execute!")
}
```

Comment: Using a lazy var is a great idea! Thank you! Just one thing, in order to make your code perfect the "return false" statement must be put inside the #else statement or you get a "Code after return will never be executed" warning when compiling for Catalyst.